# Source Control: Dealing with different projects with files in the same directories

Tags: svn, git, version-control, dvcs

We're using a tool that is vital to create our projects which puts files all over it's filestructure. For instance

The code might be stored like so

- root/code/project1
- root/code/project2
- root/code/project3

Some associated setup files might be in another directory

- root/setupfile/project1
- root/setupfile/project2
- root/setupfile/project3

It does this for a number of directories and it's a bit more nested than the simplified example above. These projects must have their files in these locations or else they can't be used.

We use a piece of software to run our projects on an external piece of kit and it requires this rather odd setup. The software can only be run from Windows.

What kind of source control system can handle this kind of layout? (My main experience is SVN so that's my reference point)
Ideally we'd only want to checkout the projects that we're currently working on. It would be nice to view all files from a particular project tomorrow.

I could use SVN and put the root in SVN but then it's a little tiresome to pick out and checkout all these files associated with one project. I can't put the project into separate SVN repos because they can't be checked out into the same directory.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received!

Edit:

I think Symlinks are probably the way to go - thanks for the help!

Comment: You could probably work around the issue with symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using symbolic links?  For example, suppose I checkout the projects from svn into:

- /working-copies/project1
- /working-copies/project2
- /working-copies/project3

Then create symbolic links (I'm using *nix syntax here):

- ln -s /working-copies/project1/src root/code/project1
- ln -s /working-copies/project2/src root/code/project2
- ln -s /working-copies/project3/src root/code/project3
- ln -s /working-copies/project1/config root/setupfile/project1
- ln -s /working-copies/project2/config root/setupfile/project2
- ln -s /working-copies/project3/config root/setupfile/project3

Does this get you what you need for this tool?

Comment: +1, was about to suggest this but didn't know the windows command. I guess you don't either; hopefully someone can translate it.